# AngularJS Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting the error Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined when attempting to reset a form.

My controller:

```
formApp.controller('FormController', ['$scope', 
    function ($scope) {

        $scope.options = ["Opt1", "Opt2", "Opt3", "Other"];
        $scope.formData = {
            selectedOption: null,
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            email: "",
            phone: "",
            fax: "",
            comments: ""
        };

        var origData = angular.copy($scope.formData);


        $scope.submit = function () {
            // submit code goes here
        };

        $scope.reset = function () {
            $scope.formData = angular.copy(origData);

              //  $scope.financeForm.$setUntouched();
                $scope.financeForm.$setPristine();


        };

        $scope.reset();

    }
]);
```

My HTML (I've stripped out most fields to keep this minimal):

```
<form id="financeForm" name="financeForm" ng-submit="financeForm.$valid && submit()" novalidate>
    <md-content layout-padding class="autoScroll">
        <md-input-container flex md-is-error="financeForm.selectedOption.$invalid && (financeForm.$submitted || financeForm.selectedOption.$dirty)">
            <md-select required placeholder="Nature of your Enquiry" ng-model="formData.selectedOption" name="selectedOption" id="selectedOption">
                <md-option ng-repeat="opt in options" value="{{opt}}">{{opt}}</md-option>
            </md-select>
            <div ng-messages="financeForm.selectedOption.$error" ng-if="financeForm.$submitted || financeForm.selectedOption.$touched">
                <div ng-message="required">Please your enquiry option.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container>
            <label>Comments</label>
            <textarea ng-model="formData.comments" columns="1" md-maxlength="500"></textarea>
        </md-input-container>
    </md-content>

    <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="reset();">RESET</md-button>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">SUBMIT</md-button>
</form>
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please help?

Comment: Shouldnt $setPristine be added as a service to your function at the top. Just like scope

Comment: the `financeForm` hasn't been bound to your controller scope when you call `$scope.reset()`, it is only bound after the controller is initialized AFAIK. Is there a need to call `$scope.reset()` when your controller intializes? When click your reset button, you shouldn't get that error, or do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$setPristine is undefined because you need to add it as a service to your function at the top

```
function ($scope,$setPristine){...
```

That will let the function know what you mean by $setPristine

Also angular JS $setPristine only works in angularjs 1.1.* so check your version.

Answer (score 0):

check for any open function calls which is rendering the page before the form creation which may end-up in " $setPristine is undefined "
By using this code you can reset the $dirty , $name ,$untouched , $pristine ,$valid etc ... to their original boolean state. 
in html code

```
<md-button ng-click="reset(ExampleForm)">Cancel</md-button>
<md-button type="submit" ng-disabled="ExampleForm.$invalid || !ExampleForm.$dirty">Save</md-button>
```

In controller

```
    $scope.reset = function(formName){
        formName.$setPristine();
    };
```